# Showing mat-autocomplete only when the input has at least one digit

Tags: angular

Today in my code, when the focus is in the input, all the options are loaded. I want to make the **mat-autocomplete** visible only when the input has at least one digit.

My code:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="{{ 'client' | translate }}" matInput [formControl]="entitySearchCtrl" [(ngModel)]="selectedClientForSearch" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let client of relatedClients | async" [value]="client">
        {{ client.socialName }} - {{ client.cnpj_cpf }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Could you show the TS code as well, and what should happen if user enters one digit and then removes it, should it be hidden then again?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <mat-autocomplete *ngIf="selectedClientForSearch?.length >= 1" #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
```

or alternatively:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{ 'client' | translate }}" matInput [formControl]="entitySearchCtrl" [(ngModel)]="selectedClientForSearch" [matAutocomplete]="selectedClientForSearch?.length >= 1 ? auto : null">
```